# xml-parsing error in liferay 6.1.1

Tags: xml, liferay

I try to deploy my application on liferay 6.1.1 and get this error (when i tested this application on 6.0.6 everything is ok). What can it mean?

> Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.xml.DocumentException: Error on
>   line 1 of document  : The value following "version" in the XML
>   declaration must be a quoted string. Nested exception: The value
>   following "version" in the XML declaration must be a quoted string.

up: I don't know which file giving this error.
Full log

> I don't know which file giving this error...
>   All log
>   [#|2012-08-09T15:12:20.322+0400|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=17;_ThreadName=Thread-3;|15:12:20,321 ERROR [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:210] com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.xml.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document  : The value following "version" in the XML declaration must be a quoted string. Nested exception: The value following "version" in the XML declaration must be a quoted string.
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.xml.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document  : The value following "version" in the XML declaration must be a quoted string. Nested exception: The value following "version" in the XML declaration must be a quoted string.
>       at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.autoDeploy(BaseDeployer.java:201)
>       at com.liferay.portal.deploy.auto.PortletAutoDeployListener.deploy(PortletAutoDeployListener.java:84)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployDir.processFile(AutoDeployDir.java:193)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployDir.scanDirectory(AutoDeployDir.java:235)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner.run(AutoDeployScanner.java:54)
>   Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.xml.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document  : The value following "version" in the XML declaration must be a quoted string. Nested exception: The value following "version" in the XML declaration must be a quoted string.
>       at com.liferay.portal.xml.SAXReaderImpl.read(SAXReaderImpl.java:399)
>       at com.liferay.portal.xml.SAXReaderImpl.read(SAXReaderImpl.java:378)
>       at com.liferay.portal.xml.SAXReaderImpl.read(SAXReaderImpl.java:409)
>       at com.liferay.portal.kernel.xml.SAXReaderUtil.read(SAXReaderUtil.java:155)
>       at com.liferay.portal.tools.WebXMLBuilder.organizeWebXML(WebXMLBuilder.java:60)
>       at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.updateWebXml(BaseDeployer.java:2078)
>       at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.deployDirectory(BaseDeployer.java:576)
>       at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.deployFile(BaseDeployer.java:957)
>       at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.deployFile(BaseDeployer.java:889)
>       at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.autoDeploy(BaseDeployer.java:198)
>       ... 4 more
>   Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document  : The value following "version" in the XML declaration must be a quoted string. Nested exception: The value following "version" in the XML declaration must be a quoted string.
>       at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
>       at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:365)
>       at com.liferay.portal.xml.SAXReaderImpl.read(SAXReaderImpl.java:396)
>       ... 13 more
>   |#]

Comment: Do you have something in your "deploy" directory? Plugins? Which versions are they?

Comment: web.xml http://pastebin.com/bsRtCwvy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue may be with your web.xml file. I had a similar issue with a portlet that worked fine under 6.1GA1 but not 6.1GA2. When Liferay deploys portlets (and hooks, etc.), it rewrites the file and others to add filters, libraries, etc. So the error is probably not with the file as you originally created it, but with what Liferay generated.

In my case, Liferay changed the first part of web.xml from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

to something like

```
<?xml version=<filters>[other stuff]</filters>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

So it was a *modified* first line that caused the problem. I had some XML commented out using `<!-- -->` and removing those sections fixed the problem. But it's a bug IMHO.

Comment: I encountered the same problem and your workaround works, but it is indeed a Liferay bug, so I went ahead and created an issue for it: http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-29373

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to tag "display-name" in your web.xml. 
Sometimes (and this is my case) Eclipse plugin creates a web.xml using "j2ee:display-name" tag.
Deployer tries to append filter block configuration after "/display-name" tag position. 
When "j2ee:display-name" is present deployer appends filter block configuration to a bad position in file such as "version" attribute.
Replacing "j2ee:display-name" tag with "display-name" tag resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which plugin (hook, theme, portlet, etc) is causing the error, then you're going to have to check all the XML files in that folder structure and check the first line and make sure it's:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

It's going to be a tedious task, but not a lot else you can do!

If you don't know which plugin is causing the error then deploy them one by one until you find it!

Hope this helps!

Comment: find ./ -name "*.xml" -exec head -1 {} \; | grep version;
find ./ -name "*.xhtml" -exec head -1 {} \; | grep version
but everything is ok, in lib's too.

Comment: Have you tried re-creating the portlet using the 6.1.1 Plugins-SDK? Then copying across your source?